# tool for testing data between salesforce and dynamics?

Tags: data-migration

we are currently migrating from dynamicsCrm into salesforce. Our data migration mapping is 99% there and i would like to know is there a way to compare data between dynamicsCrm and salesforce.
Only option i see is exporting a random sample of data from each object in crm and then export related data from salesforce. Then compare using excel. i would like to know if there is a tool which can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

*Full disclosure, I work for Import2*

We offer a service that does just this. You can set up a sample for free to see how a migration would look with your own data here: https://www.import2.com/salesforce/from/dynamics

The sample will bring over a sample set of records and all standard mappings so you can see what your data looks like in Salesforce, and compare side by side in Dynamics. If you have custom mappings or other requirements for a full data migration, we can work with you on that as well.